# remove blank rows from result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```sql
select
    '0' as F_Stand_Code,
    '' as F_Stand_Desc
union all
select
    F_Stand,
    F_Stand
from T_ExhibitorLocation
where F_Site ='DIP2'
  and F_Bld = 'Le Meridien'
  and F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom'
  and F_ExhibitionCode='10991'
```

While executing this I am getting some blank rows in the result set like this:

[image: SSMS resultset]

Comment: We can't see your image.

Comment: Image didnt paste correctly

Comment: i am not able to add image ,becouse i dont have 10 reputation to add image

Comment: post a link to the image in your question and i will add it for you

Comment: i added my image ,,Please check into that

Comment: @jasbacker Cloud you include data from T_ExhibitorLocation ? From your query I don't see any reasons for blank row.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select '0' as F_Stand_Code,'' as F_Stand_Desc
union
Select F_Stand, F_Stand 
from T_ExhibitorLocation 
where F_Site = 'DIP2' and F_Bld = 'Le Meridien' and
     F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom' and F_ExhibitionCode = '10991'
```

My first response is that if you do not want a blank row, then don't include it.  Just use:

```
Select F_Stand, F_Stand 
from T_ExhibitorLocation 
where F_Site = 'DIP2' and F_Bld = 'Le Meridien' and
      F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom' and F_ExhibitionCode = '10991';
```

My second is to use `order by` (and I would recommend `union all`):

```
select t.*
from (select '0' as F_Stand_Code, '' as F_Stand_Desc
      union all
      Select F_Stand, F_Stand 
      from T_ExhibitorLocation 
      where F_Site = 'DIP2' and F_Bld = 'Le Meridien' and
            F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom' and F_ExhibitionCode = '10991'
     ) t
order by (case when F_Stand_Code = '0' then 1 else 0 end);
```

In general, if you want the results in a particular order, you need to include an `order by`.  There is no guarantee of the ordering of the result set.  Unless you use `order by`.

Comment: Invalid column name 'F_Stand_Code'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: showing error like that executing your second query

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what result you get but try this my idea

```
select * 
from (
   select '0' as F_Stand_Code,'' as F_Stand_Desc union Select F_Stand,F_Stand 
   from T_ExhibitorLocation 
   where F_Site ='DIP2' and F_Bld = 'Le Meridien' 
   and F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom' and F_ExhibitionCode='10991'
) q
where q.<column> ........
```

Then use where clause for filter blank record to your result set

Comment: Ok. I don't know why you get blank record in result please check your query from T_ExhibitorLocation table make sure this query not contain blank record if not contain blank record please post you query that i suggest that you say incorrect syntax

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly as your result image is blank but shouldn't it look like this

```
SELECT '0' AS F_Stand_Code, '' AS F_Stand_Desc 
UNION ALL 
SELECT F_Stand_Code, F_Stand_Desc
FROM T_ExhibitorLocation 
WHERE F_Site ='DIP2' 
AND F_Bld = 'Le Meridien' 
AND F_Hall = 'Great Ballroom'
AND F_ExhibitionCode='10991'
```

Comment: i added my image ,,Please check

Comment: i checked this query,thats removing first blank row.but in the result set am getting blank rows